# Attaining value type of nested record

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to create a function that can manipulate values of a nested Record, based off the collection name. In my example code, the value type is not being attained:

```
type Player = { name:string }
type Point = { x:number, y:number }


const collections = {
    players: {} as Record<string, Player>,
    positions: {} as Record<string, Point>,
}

type Collections = typeof collections;


function handleEntity<
    Key extends keyof Collections,
    Col extends Collections[Key],
    Val extends Col[keyof Col],
>(name:Key, value:Val){
    switch(name){
        case 'positions': value.x++ // <-- Not valid :(
    }
}
```

Why is Typescript not able to infer Val? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler generally has a hard time properly narrowing down the types of generically typed variables. The relation between `name` and `value` is understood by the compiler when you are calling the function. But narrowing the type of `value` by checking `name` in the implementation is currently not possible, at least when `name` and `value` are generic types.

We can remove the generic types and construct a union type for the parameters.

```
function handleEntity(...[name, value]: { 
    [K in keyof Collections]: [K, Collections[K][keyof Collections[K]]] 
  }[keyof Collections]
){
    switch(name){
        case 'positions': value.x++ // properly narrowed :)
    }
}

handleEntity("players", { name: "abc" })
handleEntity("positions", { x: 1, y: 0 })
```

Since the `name`, `value` tuple acts as a discriminated union, the compiler can properly narrow the type of `value` by checking the value of `name`.

If you still need `handleEntity` to be generic, you can add the generic signature as an overload.

```
function handleEntity<
    Key extends keyof Collections,
    Col extends Collections[Key],
    Val extends Col[keyof Col],
>(name:Key, value:Val): void
function handleEntity(...[name, value]: { 
    [K in keyof Collections]: [K, Collections[K][keyof Collections[K]]] 
  }[keyof Collections]
){
    switch(name){
        case 'positions': value.x++ // properly narrowed :)
    }
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-bqIO4oMRkUymAp+oMRmMSQAiCyBawpyQ4Km2FMIERKFMMGMJglE8agtORaI8rM8fhQACMkmkUAADCWgA)